# Get parameter value from web hook call back function?

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to save a value on Docusign envelope reference when we create envelope via API and that value can be received from web hook call back function ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When you create envelope, set an [Envelope Custom Field](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeCustomFields) value.

You can use an individual API call to set an EnvelopeCustomField after the envelope is created, or (usually better), you can set an EnvelopeCustomField value when you create the envelope, using the `customFields` field of the `envelopeDefinition` request object for the [Envelopes::create](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create) call.

You can also set up one or more Envelope Custom Fields at the account level so your senders can fill in the values for envelopes sent via the DocuSign web tool.

The Envelope Custom Fields will be included in the Notification Messages from DocuSign.